# MYSQL triple database selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

Suppose i have 3 different tables and i want to populate my `<select>` options with data from those tables. Is it possible to achieve this with a single query or i must do 3 separate queries?

**Notice that the tables are not related with each other.**

*table 'cities':*

```
cityId   cityName 
  1      Chicago 
  2      Houston
```

*table 'types':*

```
typeID   typeName
  1      Warm
  2      Cold
```

*table  'category':*

```
categoryID   categoryType
   1          Huge
   2          Small
```

I want to populate this select with city data:

```
<select>Cities</select>
<option value="1">Chicago</option>
<option value="2">Houston</option>
```

Another same one with types:

```
<select>Types</select>
<option value="1">Warm</option>
<option value="2">Cold</option>
```

and the last one with categories:

```
<select>Categories</select>
<option value="1">Huge</option>
<option value="2">Small</option>
```

Comment: Yes you can but how you want them to display ? it could be done using UNION.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I have 3 different <select> options and in each of them to display all the data of a single table. Ex: first <select> option to be populated with all data of cities. second <select> with all data of tpes and so on

Comment: no single query will not work in that case u need 3 queries for each of them. Doing UNION will merge all in one result set.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yeah. Ok thnx for the information. Gd to know that

Comment: whats a select construction you want? Option = value with ? i you will give more information. maybe it will posible

Comment: @Nazaret2005 I edited the question. You can check the example i wrote as further information

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible if there was a relationship between the tables together then yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 separate queries, unless there are millions of rows to display in each select box the cost of these queries is very cheap, and you won't see any database load from it.  Combining them all into one query just increases the complexity of the code you're using to render the select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
select * from cities 
join types
join category
```

The above sql code will give you three table data in one record set.

Comment: You are right but as i want to populate three different <select> tags each with a data of a single table, it will be impossible to separate data. 
What i wanted to achieve is impossible as i understood. I must use three different queries